# Determine the following probabilities: $\mathbb{P}(G=1, S=1)$, $\mathbb{P}(G=0, S=2)$.

Tags: probability

A room has $4$ cats. $2$ cats are grey and $2$ cats are black. I pick $2$ cats **at the same time**. What are the solutions to the following questions?

1. $\mathbb{P}(G=1, S=1)$
2. $\mathbb{P}(G=0, S=2)$

The "**at the same time**" part has really got me stumped. I would assume that the probability of picking a grey cat and black cat is $2/4 \cdot 2/4$ because you pick them at the same time. But because the events are dependent, then I would have to use $P(G \cap S) = P(G) + P(S) - P(G \cup S)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: At the same time or one after another, the probability remains same. You can either write it as $\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3}$ or if the phrase _at the same time_ is confusing you, write it as  $\frac{{2 \choose 1} {2 \choose 1}} {{4 \choose 2}}$

Comment: Euphemism for **without replacement**.

Answer (score 1):

Name your gray cats $g1,g2$ and the black cats $b1,b2$

You have $6$ possible pairs, namely,$$(g1,g2), (g1,b1),(g1,b2),(g2,b1),(g2,b2), (b1,b2)$$

Thus $$\mathbb{P}(G=1, S=1)=4/6 = 2/3$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(G=0, S=2)=1/6$$

Answer (score 0):

you can think of it this way if you like :

if you pick them at the same time then any group of $2$ cats has the same probability to be chosen, in how many ways can you choose two cats? $\frac{4 \cdot 3}{2}$ . In how many ways can you choose $1$ grey and $1$ black cat? $2 \cdot 2$.